# Why aren't I see anything useful in logcat when calling method from Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject
...
Log.d("log", "I see this log message")
val jsonData : JSONObject = JSONObject("NOT|JSON")
Log.d("log", "I don't get here but don't see any exception logged")
```

I don't expect to see the second log message since the JSONObject call will fail. But I don't see anything in log to indicate where the failure happened. This happens when inside an asynchronous callback. Any idea?

Comment: Your callback is not being executed. For whatever reason. It is not possible to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: When code in lambda throws exception it often being caught by function implementation (for example in Rx it will be caught and passed to `onError`)